# Azure DevOps pipeline asks to run 'az login' to setup account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've successfully run pipeline with step below to push docker image to registry. When I try to re-run it gives an **ERROR**: *Please run 'az login' to setup account*

```
- bash: az acr helm push -n $(registryName) -u $(registryLogin) -p $(registryPassword) $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/$(projectName)-$(build.buildId).tgz
  displayName: 'az acr helm push'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
```

The step is seen in the logs as below so shouldn't require any additional information (it works when run from command line on my local machine)

```
az acr helm push -n acrname -u acruser -p password /home/vsts/work/1/a/chart.tgz
```

Comment: this happen on this step?

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or private agent?

Comment: correct, on step 'az acr helm push'

Comment: pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04' so I think it is Hosted agent

Comment: what does `when I rerun` it means? does it work only once or ... ?

Comment: I run it first time and it succeeded, then next day I got the error. Even If I I create new build with the same task

Comment: @irom try to use Azure CLI task instead of bash. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops

Comment: unfortunately it requires connection service with access to ARM which I don't have rights to;(

Comment: This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513537/az-login-fails-wih-azure-devops-pipelines/54546350#54546350) is similar to this. You can check it out for workarounds while the issue is being actively looked into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [az login fails wih Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513537/az-login-fails-wih-azure-devops-pipelines)

Answer (score 2):

The [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) genuinely does need you to be [logged in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli), so az cli commands in a [bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) will fail with this error. That is expected behaviour.

Instead of using the bash task, you should use the [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops); this includes authentication against an azure subscription as part of its setup, so you will be able to run a bash script including az cli commands.

For example:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: az acr helm push
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <Name of the Azure Resource Manager service connection>
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az acr helm push -n $(registryName) -u $(registryLogin) -p $(registryPassword) $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/$(projectName)-$(build.buildId).tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens intermittently to me, the root cause was I was using `az account clear` to 'logout' from the session when I should have used `az logout`.

`az account clear` will clear ALL subscriptions in the local cache instead of the current subscription, refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-clear