# az login fails wih Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

Since Today all our build pipelines on Azure Devops fail, when trying to execute the follwoing command:

```
az acr helm push ...
```

The pipeline fails with following error:

`ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.`

We are running on Microsoft hosted agents using **Hosted Ubuntu 1604**.
Checking the latest commits for the Ubuntu image shows, that there has been a version update from **2.0.52** to **2.0.55** of the azure cli tool.

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/commit/56c54c965019c4f7456cd9af572a443df9d5d78c#diff-f87405c9dd43f633a04dd078666d61af

Maybe this version update introduced the problem. Just guessing.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Encountering the same problem, I registered a bug at Microsoft https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/444576/az-acr-helm-push-failes-in-pipeline.html

Comment: There is also a GitHub issue for this https://github.com/AzureCR/azure-cli/issues/302.  This is a behavior change in the az cli that requires a login.

Answer (score 3):

I added the following to my pipeline to downgrade azure-cli a version, and my pipeline is now passing

```
- bash: sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades azure-cli=2.0.54-1~xenial
  displayName: 'downgrade azure-cli'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been raised with the azure-cli tool team.

To proceed now you can follow any of the two workarounds as of now:

- Use Az CLI task instead of Bash script to run az commands.
- Use Hosted VS2017 agent to run az commands because this agent has 2.0.52
  version of az-cli tool which runs this command successfully (as
  against Hosted Ubuntu 1604 which has az-cli v2.0.55)

Comment: Microsoft claims so but it is another problem they solved, I had to create a new bug report, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/446195/az-acr-helm-push-failes-in-pipeline-second-try.html

Comment: Thanks user613068 for raising another bug report. The issue is being looked into now.

Answer (score 0):

**Update to @Andy answer since this command is no longer valid**.

When working with Azure DevOps Hosted agents, Some software is installed on the machine automatically. The full list can be found [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md) Ubuntu.

One of the Softwares is `Azure CLI:Latest`. Therefore, in case you want to downgrade you need to install a new version.The following command is how i managed to install new version (Bash):

```sh
sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades azure-cli=%AZ VERSION%-1~bionic
```

**Usage:**

```sh
sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades azure-cli=2.2.0-1~bionic
```

What does the trick is to use `~bionic` after specifying the version you want to install.