# ACR docker Unable to get AAD authorization tokens with message: Please run 'az login' to setup account

Tags: linux, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to clean up / delete old docker images from Azure ACR, I am using Azure devops CI/CD Pipelines, It will clean up old images from Azure ACR

Below is the code:

```
            acr='myacr.azurecr.io'
            echo $(sudo_user_password) | sudo -S az login --service-principal -u xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -p $(client_secret) --tenant xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx && echo $(sudo_user_password) | sudo -S az acr login -n myacr.azurecr.io
            
            repos=('common/best-app')
            delete_from=3

            for repo in "${repos[@]}"; do
                tags_to_delete=$(echo $(az acr repository show-tags -n ${acr} --repository ${repo} --orderby time_desc --output tsv) | cut -d ' ' -f${delete_from}-)
                for tag_to_delete in ${tags_to_delete}; do
                    az acr repository delete --yes -n ${acr} --image ${repo}:${tag_to_delete}
                done
            done
```

During running code, I am getting below error

```
Login Succeeded
WARNING: The login server endpoint suffix '.azurecr.io' is automatically omitted.
Login Succeeded
WARNING: The login server endpoint suffix '.azurecr.io' is automatically omitted.
WARNING: Unable to get AAD authorization tokens with message: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
WARNING: Unable to get admin user credentials with message: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
ERROR: Unable to authenticate using AAD or admin login credentials. Please specify both username and password in non-interactive mode.
```

Comment: Try to use the Az CLI task instead of the Bash script to run the az command and try to downgrade the version ,as the latest version is installed by default.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513537/az-login-fails-wih-azure-devops-pipelines).Also check if credentials are correct or they got expired .Please check this  [Troubleshooting-ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-troubleshoot-login)  and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal)

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT, Credentials are correct and not expired, Logs say login succeeded

Comment: @Vidya Did you manage to find an answer?